# $2\cos(x)+x=0$? Advanced trig. question.

Tags: trigonometry

Title says it all:
$$2\cos(\theta)+(\theta)=0$$
the interval should be between $0$ to $2\pi$.

Been trying to figure this out for quite a while, still no luck.
I'm trying to find if the solution exists or not.

Comment: I suppose numerical methods are out of the question?

Comment: Title doesn't say it all; do you want to find such an $x$ or just show that such an $x$ exists?

Comment: I'm inclined to believe there is no analytical way to find such an $x$. there are however a plethora of numerical methods to solve questions like this.

Comment: The title definitely doesn't say what you want.  If the problem is to solve for $x$, you should say so.  If the problem is to figure out how many solutions exist, you should say so.  If the problem is to prove that the solution is an irrational number, you should say so.  If the problem is to ask whether there is a closed form for the solution, you should say so.  If the problem is which numerical method to use, you should say so.

Comment: A numerical method is de rigeur.

Comment: You can only find a solution numerically
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2cosx%2Bx%3D0

Comment: Sorry about the question not being specific, I edited it for better understanding. I'm trying to find the solutions(In radians) that exist. We are supposed to use a few advanced trig identities to help us out.

Comment: @KapookyHandy Understand that an equation is not a question.  There is no question in your question.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If I was to say ''find the solutions of 2cos(pheta)+(pheta)=0'' would that make more sense?

Comment: That would make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the title says it all, but that is entirely wrong, as I explained in a comment.

I will **guess** that the problem is either to find a solution or to show that one exists.

**CAREFULLY** draw the graph of $y=2\cos x$.  Then **CAREFULLY** (this one's easy) draw the graph of $y=-x$.

That will tell you that exactly one solution exists, and it will tell you approximately what number $x$ is.

My guess is Newton's method will converge quickly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how hard is it to prove (or disprove) that the solution is irrational? (perhaps I'll post a question)

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi You want to show that $\cos(t)$ is irrational when $t\neq 0$ is rational.  This can probably be done by looking at the power series for cosine, and imitating the standard proof that $e$ is irrational.

Comment: @Slade : I suspect a proof of this is in a certain book by Ivan Niven that I have at hand.

Comment: @Slade: Why do we want to show that? Let's assume that a rational argument produces an irrational output for cosine, then the solution satisfies $\cos x = -x/2$, if $x$ is rational, then $\cos x$ is irrational but $-x/2$ is rational. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @Slade: Ahh, it makes perfect sense now! We get a contradiction, nice.